# Making most viewed questions friendlier for non tech savvy users

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

Tl;Dr: Lets make the most viewed questions friendlier for non tech savvy user.

---

We have several questions getting a lot views, few of them have a high number of votes, but most of them barely have votes or doesn't have any vote.

Despite of that, several of these questions have got "me too" alike answers and follow up question postes as answers and have been protected not allowing new users and network bonus users to answer them.

Some of this user might get or not a moderation comment giving feeback about how the site works, it's very likely that due to the low participation in moderation activities or any other reason many of them didn't get the comment.

Despite the low voting and low participation we continue getting new users and new visits.

Apparently a large number of our visitors aren't non-teach savvy users, so they might have difficulties to find the features that might help them to get the most from Web Applications like

- Following a posts to get a notification when a post is being updated and gets an answer

among others.

What do you suggest that might be done to help this users and all the kind of viewers of these questions in general?

---

Some statistics

- is:question views:10000 returns > 4000 questions
- is:question views:50000 returns ~1000 questions
- is:question views:100000 returns ~400 questions

Related

- [Guidance for "me too"ers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387286/289691)
- [Is it possible to make the tour more prominent to new users again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383309/289691)
- [Is a "timeout" period for new users considered or even possible at some SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383018/289691)
- [Please make the canned feedback options in the new first questions/answers queues configurable per site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369052/289691)
- [Invite low rep users to participate in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100291/289691)
- [More emphasis on scope for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293097/289691)
- [Has the idea of something like, "Before asking a question, you must read what's on-topic for this website." been explored before?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329649/289691)